# Return valid Json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm fairly new to Json and arrays and I'm just wondering whether someone can correct the code I've tried that is still outputting an invalid string.

```
$json = array(
    'posts' => array(),
);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $posts = array();
        $posts['count'] = $rowcount;
     $posts['streamitem_id'] = $row['streamitem_id'];


$json['posts'] = $posts;
echo json_encode($json);
}
```

I have used http://jsonlint.com/ and posted my returned data from firebug errors on lines 6,11 and 16 
`} {`

```
  {
    "posts": {
        "count": 4,
        "streamitem_id": "1976"
    }
} {
    "posts": {
        "count": 4,
        "streamitem_id": "1980"
    }
} {
    "posts": {
        "count": 4,
        "streamitem_id": "1099"
    }
} {
    "posts": {
        "count": 4,
        "streamitem_id": "1178"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `$rowcount` variable hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Where are lines 4, 7 and 10? Please post the entire json.

Comment: $rowcount has been initialised.by `$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);` just below my query - It wasn't relevent, just added it as it was a varaible that needed to be passed through the json array.
Also the lines can be counted from the first line to the last and it will give you the problem lines which are the opening and closing brackets which are now lines 6,11 and 16

Comment: Accepted answer below. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some have already commented with a valid answer however, I believe array_push is the most efficient method rather than redefining the $posts variable over and over.

```
$json = array(
    'posts' => array()
);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($json['posts'], $array(
        'count' => $rowcount,
        'streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id']
        )
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

PS: I noticed that you're putting $rowcount in each post array. If this is not intended, I recommend the following change:

```
$json = array(
    'posts' => array(),
    'count' => $rowcount
);
```

And then in the while loop:

```
    array_push($json['posts'], $array(
        'streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id']
        )
    );
```

This way, you can reference the post count and it won't be a waste of memory.

```
console.log(json['count']);
```

Comment: @Gateway No problem. I made an edit to account for one more thing.

Comment: Nice little edit there. 

Returned string now looks like this

  `  {
     "posts": [{
      "streamitem_id": "1976"
     }, {
      "streamitem_id": "1980"
     }, {
      "streamitem_id": "1099"
     }, {
      "streamitem_id": "1178"
     }],
     "count": 4
    }`

Comment: Accepted your answer. Brownie points for going the extra mile with the other part.

Comment: Probably easier: `$json['posts'][] = array('streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id']);`

Comment: Another way to do this (for even further optimization) is to avoid even storing the 'streamitem_id' key at all. Simply:

    array_push($json['posts'], $row['streamitem_id']); 

I only say this because you already know that 'posts' contains the stream item ids. Your js object should then look like this:

    {"posts":["1976","1980","1099","1178"], "count":4}

PS: It appears that $json['posts'][] may be faster by microseconds. I recommend doing some research on this if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you @TimothyWood I will certainly look into this. The faster the better. I've already increased site speed tonnes by changing the structure. of it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this outside of loop, you are overwriting and echoing each value instead whole at once

Inside loop

```
      $posts[] = ["count"=> $rowcount,"streamitem_id"=>$row['streamitem_id']);
```

After loop

```
  $json['posts'] = $posts;
  echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Hi @Niklesh this is now valid json but only returns one record instead of the 4 I've requested within the loop. How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
$posts = array();
$rowcount = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $posts[] = array(
       'count' => $rowcount,
       'streamitem_id' = $row['streamitem_id'],
    );
    $rowcount++;
}

$json['posts'] = $posts;
echo json_encode($json);
```